# Is this the correct connector to receive and split out an S-Video cable

Tags: connector, video, socket

I am looking for the correct connector to receive and give me access to each of the 4 signals on an S-Video cable. I have found this:

http://uk.farnell.com/pro-signal/psg01568/socket-mini-din-4pole/dp/1280741

and also this :

http://uk.farnell.com/schurter/4850-241/socket-mini-din-pcb-4pole/dp/152212

But it is hard for me to know if these parts are 'exactly' correct since they don't seem to mention S-Video and the Wikipedia page for the S-Video socket doesn't explain the technical name for this type of socket other than Mini din : [S-Video wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video)

Comment: From the Wikipedia article: "The four-pin mini-DIN connector is the most common of several S-Video connector types."

Comment: This is neither a recommendation or shopping question. OP is not asking "I want you to find me a place to buy x". OP is asking about clarification on their understanding of a electronics component or specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S-Video standard uses the German standardized Mini-Din-4 connector, which the Wikipedia article glosses over and does not name with the accurate technical name of the connector. There are 7 standardized Mini-Din variants, and many non-standard connectors that mate with some Mini-Din standard connectors. Calling it a four pin Mini-Din is like saying a 3 pin audio connector or a barrel connector. It's not explicitly clear, as even the Wikipedia article for Mini-Din shows.

But yes, those connectors are the proper ones for S-Video.

Comment: Passerby you reflect the exact answer and explanation I was hoping for - thank you. Please note the differences here @Pipe to your response.

Comment: No problem, but try not to engage in arguments here. The mods have cleaned up the comments for a reason.